# How to set SwiftUI picker font color

Tags: swiftui

I have this SwiftUI picker.  With it, picking a high, medium or low value sets the outline of the picker to the corresponding color.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var gaugeLevel: GaugeLevel = .low

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.white) 
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(gaugeLevel.color, lineWidth: 2)
                )
                .frame(width: 120, height: 25)
            
            Picker("Level", selection: $gaugeLevel) {
                ForEach(GaugeLevel.allCases, id: \.self) { level in
                    Text(level.rawValue.capitalized).tag(level)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum GaugeLevel: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case high, medium, low

    var color: Color {
        
        switch self {
        case .high:
            return .red
            
        case .medium:
            return .orange
            
        case .low:
            return .green
        }
    }
    var id: Self {self}
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Instead of this look, I want to set the background to the corresponding color (which I know how to do), **and** set the font color to white...which I haven't figured out how to do...it always stays blue.

Is there a way to set the font color with the built-in pickers?

Solution accepted as answer:

```
 Picker("Level", selection: $gaugeLevel) {
            ForEach(GaugeLevel.allCases, id: \.self) { level in
                Text(level.rawValue.capitalized).tag(level)
                    
            }
        }
        .background(gaugeLevel.color)
        .accentColor(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
```

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I want.  Accepted as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach to `...set the background to the corresponding color (which I know how to do), and set the font color to white.`, using `.background(gaugeLevel.color)` **and** `.accentColor(.white)` as shown in the example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var gaugeLevel: GaugeLevel = .low
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(gaugeLevel.color, lineWidth: 2))
                .frame(width: 150, height: 35)
            
            Picker("Level", selection: $gaugeLevel) {
                ForEach(GaugeLevel.allCases, id: \.self) { level in
                    Text(level.rawValue.capitalized).tag(level)
                }
            }
            .accentColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 35)
            .background(gaugeLevel.color)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        }
    }
}
```